# Javascript Reference Error in Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I am writing unit tests for my angularjs solution using jasmine and chutzpah and I keep getting a ReferenceError saying the it cant find a variable module...

this are the error messages I keep getting:

> Test Name:    appControllersTest encountered a declaration exception Test
>   FullName: ..\scripts_references.js::appcontrollerstest::encountered a
>   declaration exception Test Source:    ..\scripts_references.js : line 0
>   Test Outcome: Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.001 Result
>   Message:  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in
>   file:../scripts/unittest/controllerstest.js:20
>
> Test Name:    appControllersTest encountered a declaration exception Test
>   FullName: ..\scripts\unittest\controllerstest.js::appcontrollerstest::encountered
>   a declaration exception Test
>   Source:   ..\scripts\unittest\controllerstest.js : line 16 Test
>   Outcome:  Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.001 Result
>   Message:  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in
>   file:../scripts/unittest/controllerstest.js:20

this is my unit test:

```
/// <reference path="../_references.js" />
/// <reference path="../AngularJSApp/controllers.js" />

describe("appControllersTest", function () {
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(module("appMain"));

    describe("RRCtrl", function () {

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
            $scope = {};
            $controller("RRCtrl", { $scope: $scope });
        }));

        it("JavaTestTest", function ($controller) {
            expect(scope.$root.title).toBe("");
        });
    });
});
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of error and how do you fix it?

Comment: Where is the module function defined?

Comment: i put it in /AngularJSApp/app.js

Comment: i tried to add a reference path to the whole AngularJSApp folder but i still got the same error message.

Comment: the module is defined as:
var appMain= angular.module("appMain", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate','ngDraggable', 'SharedServices', 'DataServices' ]);

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong. Some of the references where declared in the wrong order in _reference.js. After changing it manually it worked.